# Is there a function in Laravel Livewire that allows the value property of a html element to be passed into a function?

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

Is there a function in Laravel Livewire that allows the value property of a html element (be it a radio button, checkbox, dropdown list or textbox) to be passed into a function?

For example: I have on a page a list. This list consists of different cooked dishes. I select a dish from the list by clicking on it and the value passed. Can this value be passed into a function?

**LiveWire Controller**

```php
    
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Livewire;
    
    use Livewire\Component;
    
    class Dishes extends Component
    {
    
        public function showRecipe($value)
        {
            //query database or some conditional logic
        }
    
    
        public function render()
        {
    
                return view('livewire.dishes')
    
        }
    
    }
```

**LiveWire Component**

```html
    <div>
    <ul>
        <li value="pizza" wire:click="showRecipe(this.value)">Pizza</li>
        <li value="cherry_pie" wire:click="showRecipe(this.value)">Cherry Pie</li>
        <li value="beef_stronganoff" wire:click="showRecipe(this.value)">Beef Stroganoff</li>
        <li value="caesar_salad" wire:click="showRecipe(this.value)">Caesar Salad</li>
        <li value="lobster_newburg" wire:click="showRecipe(this.value)">Lobster Newburg</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`value` is not a valid attribute on an `<li>` tag. However, you can put an anchor-tag with a "prevent default" action it, or just keep the `wire:click` on the `li` and pass the data directly to the method.

```php
<div>
    <ul>
        <li wire:click="showRecipe('pizza')">Pizza</li>
        <li wire:click="showRecipe('cherry_pie')">Cherry Pie</li>
        <li wire:click="showRecipe('beef_stronganoff')">Beef Stroganoff</li>
        <li wire:click="showRecipe('caesar_salad')">Caesar Salad</li>
        <li wire:click="showRecipe('lobster_newburg')">Lobster Newburg</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you generate this in a loop with PHP/blade, you should use `wire:key` on it. The key should be something unique, so Livewire can keep track of each individual record.

```php
<div>
    <ul>
        @foreach([
            'pizza' => 'Pizza',
            'cherry_pie' => 'Cherry Pie',
            'beef_stronganoff' => 'Beef Stroganoff',
            'caesar_salad' => 'Caesar Salad',
            'lobster_newburg' => 'Lobster Newburg',
        ] as $value=>$name)
            <li wire:key="dish-{{ $loop->index }}" wire:click="showRecipe('{{ $value }}')">{{ $name }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```